# How much data can be stored in a bytes type in a smart contract?

Tags: contract-development, gas, storage, bytes, data-types

What are some estimates of how much data can be stored in a `bytes` type in a smart contract?

```
contract test {
    bytes data;
    function storeData(bytes _data) {
        data = _data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the limit would be the gas cost of the transaction calling `storeData`. For the gas cost, the upper limit is around 8M gas units per block in the current Ethereum mainnet.

You can split `storeData` to store segments at a time instead of all data at a time. In this way, you can split storing data over infinite number of transactions and then only your ETH supply is limiting how much data you can store in the blockchain.